# Data passing through routing in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to pass the data through router in Angular 4.

I am passing data from following function

```
onEdit(event)
{
    console.log(event.data);

            this.router.navigate(['pages/details'],event.data);


}
```

And I am receiving it like follows:

```
export class DetailsComponent {
data : any;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.data = params;
            console.log(params);
        });
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

But its not giving me the data I have passed. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass via *queryParams*,  you can try

```
this.router.navigate(['pages/details'], { queryParams: event.data });
```

Second parameter of the `navigate` method accepts an object of type [**NavigationExtras**](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras).

Comment: it worked thnks.

Comment: @FaisalAmdani try when you retrieve it  `console.log(params.queryParams);`

Comment: your above ans works for me.